# How to load polymer components correctly

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, vaadin-elements

I have a question with loading polymer element. When i configure my `bower.json` file dependency not loading correctly.

Here is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "Example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "https://vaadin.com/license/cvtl-1",
  "authors": [
    "Vaadin Ltd"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^2.0.0",
    "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#^2.0.0",
    "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#^2.0.0",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0",
    "iron-icon": "^2.0.0",
    "paper-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "vaadin": "vaadin/vaadin#10.0.0-alpha8",
    "vaadin-grid": "vaadin/vaadin-grid#4.1.0-beta1",
    "vaadin-charts": "vaadin/vaadin-charts#6.0.0-alpha10",
    "vaadin-valo-theme": "vaadin/vaadin-valo-theme#2.0.0-alpha5",
    "vaadin-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "app-layout": "polymerelements/app-layout#2.1.0"
    // "wysiwyg-e" : "^2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "Polymer/web-component-tester#^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "vaadin-grid": "4.1.0-beta1",
    "vaadin-charts": "6.0.0-alpha10",
    "vaadin-valo-theme": "2.0.0-alpha5"
  }
}
```

I need to load correctly `app-layout` and `wysiwyg-e`. What did i do wrong ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the other dependencies you're loading from the same directory, I would say that the path is case sensitive, and that for `app-layout` you only used lower case letters, instead of the PascalCase format, so maybe you should try:

```
"app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#2.0.1",
```

(I am guessing you meant 2.0.1 there, not 2.1.0, since 2.0.5 seems to be the most recent version)

And for `wysiwyg-e` you can try:

```
"wysiwyg-e": "miztroh/wysiwyg-e#^2.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for version conflicts with such bower.json file is that the individual Vaadin components (`vaadin-grid`, `vaadin-charts`, etc) are effectively included twice: once through the `vaadin/vaadin` meta-package and the second time explicitly.

Generally, having a bower dependency only to the `vaadin` meta-package should be enough:

```
"dependencies": {
  "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^2.0.0",
  "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#^2.0.0",
  "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#^2.0.0",
  "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0",
  "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0",
  "iron-icon": "^2.0.0",
  "paper-toast": "^2.0.0",
  "vaadin": "vaadin/vaadin#10.0.0-alpha8",
  "wysiwyg-e": "^2.1.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "web-component-tester": "Polymer/web-component-tester#^6.0.0"
}
```

This will pull a matching set of versions of `vaadin-grid`, `vaadin-charts`, and all other Vaadin components.

Note also, that you seem to be using an outdated alpha8 version. Please consider upgrading to the latest beta: [`vaadin/vaadin#10.0.0-beta8`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/releases/tag/v10.0.0-beta8).

In case if you really need to use a specific version of say `vaadin-grid`, the way to do it is either to *not* use the `vaadin` meta-dependency at all, or to specify that version of it which includes the desired version of `vaadin-grid` (e.g. `vaadin-grid#4.1.0-alpha1` is a part of `vaadin#10.0.0-alpha5`, but there is not version of the `vaadin` meta-package that includes the `4.1.0-beta1` version of `vaadin-grid`).